# How to find median using Google BigQuery based on both the user id and the number of levels the ID has visited?

Tags: mysql, sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have about 100,000 user IDs who are visiting n number of levels. I need to find the overall median of the users and levels visited by each.

I've tried to use AVG based on the number of IDs on each level and the total IDs who started the application. The values are varying alot.

To find IDs who started the application.

```
SELECT 
event_names, COUNT(DISTINCT id) uniques, COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM xyz.analytics_111.xyz 
WHERE (date BETWEEN "20191018" AND "20191024") AND version = "3.1" AND event_names in ("app_open","internet") AND platform = "ANDROID" 
AND id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM abc.analytics_111.abc WHERE event_names = "internet" AND internet_status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY event_names
```

To find total users on each level.

```
SELECT event_names, story_name, level, COUNT(DISTINCT id) uniques, COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM xyz.analytics_111.xyz WHERE (date BETWEEN "20191018" AND "20191024") AND version = "3.1" AND event_names in ("start_level","end_level") AND platform = "ANDROID" AND id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM abc.analytics_111.abc 
WHERE event_names = "internet" AND internet_status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY event_names, story_name, level ORDER BY event_names DESC, story_name, level
```

After this I'm dividing the Sum of User ID count on all levels by the number of User ID who started the application to get the AVG of Levels visited by each user. Is there a way to find a median?

Comment: can you paste the queries you've tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to have everything together, and explain what kind of median you expect as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't have enough details for a complete answer, but with the elements you've given us:

- Don't use `AVG`, when you want `MEDIAN`

To calculate a median you can do something like:

```
SELECT level_id, fhoffa.x.median(ARRAY_AGG(some_number))
FROM `table`
GROUP BY level_id
```

`bqutil.fn.median()` is a public UDF we shared with the world:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83

---

Now, with the extra details you provided, if you want

> to get the AVG of Levels visited by each user

, then:

```
SELECT AVG(levels) avg_levels_for_users
FROM (
  SELECT id user, COUNT(DISTINCT level) levels
  FROM `....`
  GROUP BY user
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. I've used  fhoffa.x.median(ARRAY_AGG(some_number)) for my queries.

Answer (score 0):

recommend using APPROX_QUANTILES({field}, 4)[2]
instead of fhoffa.x.median as on real-world sizable queries the latter one is much more likely getting into "the query could not be executed in the allotted memory" trouble.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).